# How can I tell (in script) how many Terminals are open in mac os x?

Tags: macos, terminal

how can I tell how many Terminal windows (in mac os x) are currently opened?
this needs to be done from a shell script.

thanks,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This script does what you ask for, you use `osascript` to run it from the cmd line.

```
tell application "Terminal"
    set c to 0
    repeat with i from 1 to (count of windows)
        set c to c + (count of tabs in window i)
    end repeat
    c
end tell
```

---

**Edit by Bavarious:** In order to use Adam’s AppleScript inside a shell script, you can do the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
read -d '' OSASCRIPT << EOF
    tell application "Terminal"
        set c to 0
        repeat with i from 1 to (count of windows)
            set c to c + (count of tabs in window i)
        end repeat
        c
end tell
EOF

nwindows=$(osascript -e "${OSASCRIPT}")
```

Comment: I’ve edited your answer to include how to invoke the AppleScript from a bash script.

Comment: or use the script as is with the shebang `#!/usr/bin/osascript`

Comment: Oh, I hadn’t even considered that the shebang would work. Well, now the OP has two solutions. :)

Comment: Thanks so much, this combination is *exactly* what I needed ;]

Answer (score 4):

```
cnt=$(w -h | grep "^$(whoami) *s[^ ]* *-"|wc -l)
echo Your current terminal sessions: $cnt
```

Comment: this won't tell you the number of terminal windows open... just the number of logged in sessions.

Comment: w | wc -l will tell you the number of logged sesions. The above grep will filter only sessions from the local computer, so only those what must have a terminal. (ofc, if here is a problem with a `screen` command) - but it is usually enough.