# How to find the number of Tabs open in a Mac Terminal

Tags: macos, shell, terminal, applescript

I want to find the number of terminals open in a mac for certain operations. Is there any way to do it without using top?

Comment: To do this with applescript check [here ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6172663/how-can-i-tell-in-script-how-many-terminals-are-open-in-mac-os-x)

Comment: Thanks, @SarilSudhakaran. That's exactly what I wanted

Answer (score 0):

You can use following command to get the number of Tabs open in a Mac Terminal :

`ps -afx | grep "\-bash" | grep -iv "grep" | wc -l`

```
$ ps -afx | grep "\-bash" | grep -iv "grep" | wc -l
       4
$
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ps -el | grep bash | wc -l
```

works perfect for me.